# Laotion (Thai/Viet) Style Sticky Rice, after making sticky rice do you knead the rice in something specific?

Tags: rice, thai-cuisine, vietnamese-cuisine

I have been trying to replicate some sticky rice that I ate during my childhood.  I know you have to rinse the glutinous rice several times and let it soak for a good period of time.  I then used my rice cooker instead of my bamboo steamer and it did a pretty good job.
(I am using calrose rice)

After removing from the rice cooker the rice is extremely sticky, I remember watching my friend's dad prepare this every morning and he would knead the rice in a substance on the counter top.  I believe that it was rice flour.  Any ideas on if this is what should be used to knead the rice in?  I am not talking about sushi rice.  I will make that some other time.

I have read all the posts on sticky rice on Seasoned Advice but have came up with nothing regarding this.  (Also, searched the web)

Comment: Can you describe the end product? I think there's more than one thing made of sticky rice in Laotian/Thai/Viet cuisine.

Comment: The end product is literally "lao/thai/viet" sticky rice.  I intend on eating this with my hands.

Comment: have you tried getting hold of your friends dad? Jasmine rice is a good place to start, no wash and the less water the stickier. (To a point obviously. 1.4:1 water:rice being the limit)

Comment: Are you asking about [mochi](http://images.tastespotting.com/thumbnails/112162.jpg)? I'm not too familiar with the differences from Japanese mochi, but I do remember eating a lot of mochi with [chả](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gi%C3%B2_l%E1%BB%A5a) and fish sauce from vietnamese bakeries.

Comment: No not mochi, that looks very interesting though, would like to try that and ferdies yes, i have tried contacting him but that was decades ago and i have no idea where he lives now.

Comment: @ferdiesfoodlab Sticky rice here is referring to glutinous rice, which is definitely not jasmine rice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surveyed many recipes available by googling "Loation sticky rice", "Thai sticky rice" and "Viet sticky rice".

None of them mentioned kneading anything in after 30 or 40 recipes, although many mention fluffing, folding, or stirring the rice after cooking or steaming to manage the texture.

Several did mention that it is appropriate for eating with one's hands.  The key may be the variety of rice that is used.  Short grained glutinous rice will have the sticky texture desired.

[image]

Comment: After further research looks like calrose is medium grain, but on top of that it sounds like using a rice cooker version a bamboo steamer makes it difficult to get the consistency that I was looking for.  Still not sure about what was being kneaded into the rice.  Marking as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thai people we separate sticky rice on a big round tray after steam it to cool down and get rid of steam heat which will make rice is over cook and become too sticky. 
If you want to cook from rice cooker soak sticky rice over night and in the morning wash it with water 2-3 times then add water about the same level of sticky rice if you add water too much it will too sticky.

Enjoy your meal !

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not an advertising platform - you can certainly link to your site on your profile page, or even in an answer if it has some pertinent information on it, but otherwise we'd prefer you focus on answering the question.